# Chromedriver - "cannot determine loading status from tab crashed"

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a testing app on Heroku using Chromedriver. Every once in a while, I keep getting an error: "cannot determine loading status from tab crashed". After checking different threads, apparently it is caused by "dev/shm usage". I'm running it with disable dev/shm usage argument, but am still getting an error. Any ideas what other reasons can cause this issue? Here is a sample code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver.set_window_size(1600, 1080)
load_cookie(driver)
driver.get(url)
```